# Connectivity of a random regular graph of degree $d$

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, randomness, random-graphs

An Erdős–Rényi graph over $n$ vertices and average degree $d$ is not connected w.h.p. iff $d < \log n$. I was wondering for what the degree $d$ would a random regular graph of degree $d$ be connected? In particular will this be connected for some degree less than $\log n$?

Comment: BTW, Vivek, you should accept answers if they do answer the question as posed.

Comment: I will to read/glance the paper and then accept the answer. Thanks for letting me know though!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For constant $d \geq 3$, a random $d$-regular graph is connected with high probability. In fact, it is an expander with high probability. See for example [this note](https://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-readings/ellis11expansion.pdf) by David Ellis. Friedman even showed that a random $d$-regular graph has nearly optimal spectral gap, with high probability.

Comment: The link you offered  is not found now.

Comment: how to prove the existence of $d$-regular expander graph with probabilistic method?

Comment: See my answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/132509/34591

Comment: @Jxb I noticed that the link in the MO answer was broken. Sorry about that - I just have fixed it.